# fsyacc errors when building in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild, f#, fsyacc

I'm using fsyacc within Visual Studio (using the Parsed Language Starter template), but the build output doesn't show the line/column where the error occured (only: *fsyacc exited with code 1*). I have to build from the command prompt to get this information, somewhat negating the benefit of VS integration.

Is there a way to show this in the output window?

#### EDIT

Here are some examples of errors that aren't shown in the output window.

```
Parser.fsy(74,4): error: parse error
```

and

```
building tables
FSYACC: error FSY000: NonTerminal 'query' has no productions
```

Here's success output that would be nice to see also:

```
building tables
computing first function...time: 00:00:00.1318603
building kernels...time: 00:00:00.1027372
building kernel table...time: 00:00:00.0533044
computing lookahead relations.............................
..............time: 00:00:00.0517415
building lookahead table...time: 00:00:00.0207993
building action table...state 29: shift/reduce error on AS
state 49: shift/reduce error on OR
state 49: shift/reduce error on AND
...
time: 00:00:00.1457792
building goto table...time: 00:00:00.0035636
returning tables.
39 shift/reduce conflicts
62 states
11 nonterminals
41 terminals
46 productions
#rows in action table: 62
```

Comment: It does give red-squiggles in the .fsy file, sort of, some times (might need to clean solution and rebuild).

Comment: I've used fsyacc quite a bit and haven't seen that yet. Maybe my configuration is messed up.

Comment: Actually, you may be right, I just tried it out and couldn't create a scenario that produced red-squiggles. But I did get the red-squiggles with my .fsl fslex file, must have been thinking of that.

Comment: @StephenSwensen: I found the red squiggles. The fsy and fsl files must parse first. Once that happens, some errors are highlighted.

Comment: Possibly is it that fsyacc is outputting to stderr rather than stdout?  I wonder if wrapping it in a script to redirect the output will fix it?

Comment: @Brian: No, it's going to stdout.

Comment: Yeah, when I use fslex/fsyacc it behaves the same way (no detailed output in the Output window). I just have a separate console window open for debugging purposes. It would be nice if this worked, but I guess this is quite a minority feature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using Parsed Language Starter template, I build parser/lexer by using `Pre-build event` in `Build Events` from VS Project Properties:

```
fslex "$(ProjectDir)Lexer.fsl"
fsyacc --module Grammar "$(ProjectDir)Grammar.fsy"
```

It is not very desirable since I have to set fsyacc/fslex in Path environment variable. Whenever I don't want to rebuild parser/lexer, I have to comment out the following part in fsproj file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <PreBuildEvent>fslex "$(ProjectDir)Lexer.fsl"
                 fsyacc --module Grammar "$(ProjectDir)Grammar.fsy"
  </PreBuildEvent>
</PropertyGroup>
```

However, the winning point is clear. We have all messages including errors and success output in `stdout` which is convenient for debugging.